# Unable to resolve service to a factory; are you certain you provided it during configuration?

Tags: php

could you please tell me what could be wrong. I use the factory template, in the configs I connected everything in the factory itself through the container and return it to the class. I get the error "Unable to convert service 'Http\Client\HttpClient' to a factory; are you sure you specified it during configuration?"
Here is my code:

Class :

```
private $httpClient;

    /**
     * @param OrderService $orderService
     * @param EntityManager $entityManager
     * @param HttpClient $httpClient
     */
    public function __construct(OrderService $orderService, EntityManager $entityManager, HttpClient $httpClient)
    {
        $this->orderService = $orderService;
        $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
        $this->httpClient = $httpClient;
    }
```

Factory :

```
public function __invoke(ContainerInterface $container, $requestedName, array $options = null)
{
    $orderService = $container->get(OrderService::class);
    $entityManager = $container->get(EntityManager::class);
    $httpClient = $container->get(HttpClient::class);
    return new PayKeeperPaymentService($orderService, $entityManager, $httpClient);
}
```

Config :

```
'service_manager' => [
    'factories' => [
        PayKeeperPaymentService::class => PayKeeperPaymentServiceFactory::class
    ],
],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I checked the HttpClient file, it turns out it's an interface, not a class.